# Returning a Postgres UUID with an Hibernate SQLQuery

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, uuid

I have read several questions with answers about `PostgreSQL`, `Hibernate` and `UUID`s, but none was about this precise issue I face.

Check this domain entity:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.UUID;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "my.UUIDGenerator")
    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid")
    private UUID                id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "account")
    private Account             account;

    @Type(type = "pg-uuid")
    @Column(name = "user_created")
    private UUID                userCreated;

    @Column(name = "message", columnDefinition = "text")
    private String              message;
}
```

I want to query it with this SQL query:

```
StatelessSession session = sessionFactory.openStatelessSession();
sql = "select "
+ "cast(id as varchar) as \"id\" " // ugly, but works
// + "id " // does not work, produces o.h.MappingException: No Dialect mapping for JDBC type: 1111
+ "from message m "
+ "where m.account = :account "
+ "and m.chat = :chatId ";

SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("account", accountId);
query.setParameter("chatId", chatId);
query.setResultTransformer(AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.INSTANCE);
List<Map<String, Object>> result = query.list();
session.close();
```

As indicated in the code, returning the UUID does not work.

The only (bad) way to get the value returned is to cast it to a varchar.

The dialect `Hibernate` uses is configured like this:

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
```

For information completeness, the database table is defined like this:

```
create table message (
   id             uuid        not null,
   user_created   uuid,
   message        text,
   account        uuid,
   chat           uuid
);

alter table public.message add constraint message_pkey primary key (id);
```

I use the following environment:

- Linux 4.8.14
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b16)
- PostgreSQL 9.5.5
- Hibernate 5.0.11.Final
- Spring Boot 1.4.2.RELEASE

Comment: What Hibernate dialect are you using?

Comment: spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

Comment: But you're using Hibernate directly, not through JPA. Are you sure it's still being configured with that dialect?

Comment: The dialect is set to `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect`, I just checked the value from code at runtime. The Spring Boot property is maybe just named a bit confusingly.

Comment: Spring Boot's general opinion is that you're using the standard JPA rather than the nonstandard Hibernate, which is why that particular name. I'm afraid I'll have to bow out at this point; I've not had this issue (though I didn't specify `@Type` explicitly and used Hibernate through the JPA interface, not manually).

Comment: I have tried commenting-out the dialect parameter, so it auto-detects. And it comes up with `org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect` (Note `94` vs `9`. The Exception still happens though.

Comment: All of the Postgres 9 dialects should support the UUID type.

Comment: Yes I know that's what I read in many questions and answers and non-so posts. But probably those cases were all without Spring Boot. I know also that Spring Boot uses JPA by default, but you can autowire a Hibernate SessionFactory and use the Hibernate Session and its API directly.

Answer (score 0):

**In my case this works**

```
    List<String> messageIdStringArrayList
        = currentSession().createSQLQuery(String.format(
            "select cast(m.id as varchar) " +
                    "from message m " +
                    "where m.account = '%s' " +
                    "and " +
                    "m.chat = '%s'",
            String.valueOf(accountId), String.valueOf(chatId))).list();

    List<UUID> messageIdArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(messageIdStringArrayList)) {
        for (String idString : messageIdStringArrayList) {
            messageIdArrayList.add(UUID.fromString(idString));
        }
    }
```